# How can I get a running thread's start address on linux?

Tags: linux, multithreading, memory-address

## Problem Statement

I'm trying to get the address of a running thread's start_routine as passed in the pthread_create() call.

## Research so far

It is apparently not in /proc/[tid]/stat or /proc/[tid]/status.

I found that start_routine is a member of struct pthread and gets set by pthread_create.[1]
If I knew the address of this struct, I could read the start_routine address.

I also found td_thr_get_info defined in the debugging library thread_db.h.[2]
It fills a struct with information about the thread, including the start function.[3] But it needs a struct td_thragent as an argument and I don't know how to create it properly.

## Links

[1] http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/nptl/pthread_create.c?v=GLIBC27;im=excerpts#L455

[2] http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/nptl_db/td_thr_get_info.c?v=GLIBC27#L27

[3] See comment, because I'm not allowed to post more than 2 links.

Comment: [3] http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/nptl_db/thread_db.h?v=GLIBC27#L259

Comment: Why do you ask, and why do you need this? Please edit your question to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't, and I could even imagine a very wild scenario where it could not exist at the moment you are querying it.

Let's suppose that the initial thread start routine `void*foo_start(void*)` is in some `dlopen`-ed dynamic shared library  `libfoo.so`.

Let's imagine that `foo_start`  is making a [tail-recursive call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) to `bar`, and that `bar` function is `dlclose`-ing `libfoo.so` and later calling some of your routine querying that start. It is an wild address in some defunct segment (which has been `munmap`-ed by `dlclose` called by `bar`)!

So, even if you hack your `libc` to retrieve the start routine of a thread, that does not make much sense. BTW, you could look into [MUSL libc](http://musl-lib.org/), its [src/thread/pthread_create.c](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/thread/pthread_create.c) file is quite readable.

<sup>NB: on some occasions, recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (e.g. 4.8 or 4.9) when asked to optimize a lot (e.g. `-O3`) are able to generate tail recursive calls from C code.</sup>

Comment: I don't want to use the function, I just want to know it's address. Doesn't really matter if the function's dll is unloaded.

Comment: Why do you want to know the address of the start function? What for?